# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c1' of undefined but can not find what is typed wrong

Tags: javascript, uncaught-exception

I have done lots of research, and I have made this error before on other pages, and found those errors, but this time I can not find what is wrong. One time, merely changing the name of the function to codeWord which was shorter then the original worked. Another time, I was missing a number after the "c" or have two numbers the same. This time, none of that is appears to be the issue. What am I doing wrong THIS TIME? :P Thanks! .ps Have looked over this code for two days. My friend can not find my error either, but he isn't well versed in JS.

Also, error occurs in both Chrome and Firefox, so I am assuming I made a coding error somewheres. Thanks!

Update: I am using 4.01 transitional for my html. And, I did check to be sure that "crossWord" was the same in all three spots. Also, I did not include all of the "letters" that went between the groups of input boxes, as those are all basic html anyway and is not where the error would lie. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function crossWord(){
if (document.form.c1.value=="="
&& document.form.c2.value=="="
&& document.form.c3.value=="="
&& document.form.c4.value=="="
&& document.form.c5.value=="="
&& document.form.c6.value=="="
&& document.form.c7.value=="="
&& document.form.c8.value=="="
&& document.form.c9.value=="="
&& document.form.c10.value=="="
&& document.form.c11.value=="="
&& document.form.c12.value=="="
&& document.form.c13.value=="="
&& document.form.c14.value=="1"
&& document.form.c15.value=="1"
&& document.form.c16.value=="1"
&& document.form.c17.value=="1"
&& document.form.c18.value=="1"
&& document.form.c19.value=="1"
&& document.form.c20.value=="1"
&& document.form.c21.value=="="
&& document.form.c22.value=="="
&& document.form.c23.value=="="
&& document.form.c24.value=="="
&& document.form.c25.value=="="
&& document.form.c26.value=="="
&& document.form.c27.value=="="
&& document.form.c28.value=="="
&& document.form.c29.value=="="
&& document.form.c30.value=="="
&& document.form.c31.value=="="
&& document.form.c32.value=="="
&& document.form.c33.value=="="
&& document.form.c34.value=="1"
&& document.form.c35.value=="1"
&& document.form.c36.value=="1"
&& document.form.c37.value=="1"
&& document.form.c38.value=="1"
&& document.form.c39.value=="1"
&& document.form.c40.value=="="
&& document.form.c41.value=="="
&& document.form.c42.value=="="
&& document.form.c43.value=="="
&& document.form.c44.value=="1"
&& document.form.c45.value=="="
&& document.form.c46.value=="="
&& document.form.c47.value=="="
&& document.form.c48.value=="="
&& document.form.c49.value=="="
&& document.form.c50.value=="="
&& document.form.c51.value=="="
&& document.form.c52.value=="="
&& document.form.c53.value=="="
&& document.form.c54.value=="1"
&& document.form.c55.value=="1"
&& document.form.c56.value=="="
&& document.form.c57.value=="="
&& document.form.c58.value=="1"
&& document.form.c59.value=="1"
&& document.form.c60.value=="="
&& document.form.c61.value=="="
&& document.form.c62.value=="="
&& document.form.c63.value=="="
&& document.form.c64.value=="1"
&& document.form.c65.value=="1"
&& document.form.c66.value=="="
&& document.form.c67.value=="="
&& document.form.c68.value=="1"
&& document.form.c69.value=="1"
&& document.form.c70.value=="="
&& document.form.c71.value=="="
&& document.form.c72.value=="="
&& document.form.c73.value=="="
&& document.form.c74.value=="="
&& document.form.c75.value=="="
&& document.form.c76.value=="="
&& document.form.c77.value=="="
&& document.form.c78.value=="="
&& document.form.c79.value=="="
&& document.form.c80.value=="="
&& document.form.c81.value=="="
&& document.form.c82.value=="="
&& document.form.c83.value=="="
&& document.form.c84.value=="1"
&& document.form.c85.value=="1"
&& document.form.c86.value=="1"
&& document.form.c87.value=="1"
&& document.form.c88.value=="1"
&& document.form.c89.value=="1"
&& document.form.c90.value=="="
&& document.form.c91.value=="="
&& document.form.c92.value=="="
&& document.form.c93.value=="="
&& document.form.c94.value=="="
&& document.form.c95.value=="="
&& document.form.c96.value=="="
&& document.form.c97.value=="="
&& document.form.c98.value=="="
&& document.form.c99.value=="1"
&& document.form.c100.value=="="
)
alert("Congratulations! All is correct!")

else {alert("Not correct. Please check your answers.")}
}

</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("crossWord").reset();
}
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="alert('Use = for underlining.')">

<table>
<tr><td colspan="11"><img src="http://linkhere.html" width="700px" height="4px" alt=""></td></tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="11">
<table>
<form id="crossWord">

<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td class="grey"> 1 </td>
<td class="grey"> 2 </td>
<td class="grey"> 3 </td>
<td class="grey"> 4 </td>
<td class="grey"> 5 </td>
<td class="grey"> 6 </td>
<td class="grey"> 7 </td>
<td class="grey"> 8 </td>
<td class="grey"> 9 </td>
<td class="grey"> 10 </td>
</tr>

<!-- 1 -->
<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td class="grey"> N </td>
<td class="grey"> A </td>
<td class="grey"> U </td>
<td class="grey"> F </td>
<td class="grey"> G </td>
<td class="grey"> E </td>
<td class="grey"> R </td>
<td class="grey"> E </td>
<td class="grey"> G </td>
<td class="grey"> T </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c1" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c2" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c3" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c4" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c5" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c6" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c7" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c8" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c9" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c10" size="1">  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c11" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c12" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c13" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c14" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c15" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c16" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c17" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c18" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c19" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c20" size="1">  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c21" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c22" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c23" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c24" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c25" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c26" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c27" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c28" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c29" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c30" size="1">  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c31" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c32" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c33" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c34" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c35" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c36" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c37" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c38" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c39" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c40" size="1">  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c41" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c42" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c43" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c44" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c45" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c46" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c47" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c48" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c49" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c50" size="1">  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c51" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c52" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c53" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c54" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c55" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c56" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c57" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c58" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c59" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c60" size="1">  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c61" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c62" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c63" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c64" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c65" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c66" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c67" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c68" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c69" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c70" size="1">  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c71" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c72" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c73" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c74" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c75" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c76" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c77" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c78" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c79" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c80" size="1">  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c81" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c82" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c83" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c84" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c85" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c86" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c87" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c88" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c89" size="1">  </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c90" size="1">  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c91" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c92" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c93" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c94" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c95" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c96" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c97" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c98" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c99" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c100" size="1"> </td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
</td>


    <tr>
    <td class="lhc"><input type="button" value="Check Puzzle" onClick="crossWord()"></td>

    <td class="lhc"><input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="myFunction()" /></td>
    <td class="lhc"><a href="/http://linkhere.html" class="blkn"> Crossword Navigation </a> </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form has no "name", so it cannot be referred do as a member of the document.  Change it to `<form id="crossWord" name="form">`

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I forgot to check that section. I feel like an idiot! I knew it was something really obvious that I had done wrong.